# Upload track to SoundCloud with javascript API respond Internal Server Error

Tags: javascript, html, soundcloud

I'm trying to upload a track to SoundCloud via JAVASCRIPT API, with this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Upload track</title>
  <script src="https://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk/sdk-3.0.0.js"></script>
  <script>
    var blob = "MY_BLOB";
    SC.initialize({
      client_id: 'MY_CLIENT_ID',
      oauth_token: 'MY_TOKEN',
      refresh_token: 'MY_REFRESH_TOKEN'
    });
    var upload = SC.upload({
      file: blob, // a Blob of your WAV, MP3...
      title: 'HTML test',
      genre: 'Electronic',
      description: 'This is a good! track'
    });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

I get the **oauth_token** and ***refresh_token***  from a previous request.
The response I get is:

```
{"errors":[{"error_message":"500 - Internal Server Error"}]}
```

I thought that my ***blob*** was incorrect, but if I put it in an ***audio*** tag:

```
<audio controls>
  <source src="MY_BLOB" type="audio/ogg">
</audio>
```

and it works.
That is to say the ***blob*** not is the problem.
What is the problem?

Comment: You should add your solution as an answer to this question - and then accept it.

Answer (score 1):

You should try as per

```
<script src="https://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk/sdk-3.0.0.js"></script>
<script>

// When you have recorded a song with the SDK or any Web Audio application,
// you can upload it if it's in a format that is accepted
SC.upload({
  file: theBlob, // a Blob of your WAV, MP3...
  title: 'This is my sound'
});
</script>
```

Source = https://developers.soundcloud.com/docs/api/guide#uploading

Comment: The result is _nothing_ on HTML Document... with this **code**